# Calculate a Slide rate commission per agent with MySQL... AND in ON statement?

Tags: mysql

I have set up a sqlfiddle for this question : [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d9fa1/3/0)

I have an issue calculating a slide rate commission for Agents, based on their Sales (called NGR here).

The commission table is the following:

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| id |  tier_min  | tier_max | com_rate | dif_rate | agent  |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1 |          0 |   100000 |     0.15 |     0.15 | AGENT4 |
|  3 | 100000.001 |   200000 |      0.2 |     0.05 | AGENT4 |
|  4 | 200000.001 |   300000 |     0.25 |     0.05 | AGENT4 |
|  5 | 300000.001 |   500000 |      0.3 |     0.05 | AGENT4 |
|  6 | 500000.001 | 10000000 |     0.35 |     0.05 | AGENT4 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

For example, if an Agent has $120000 sales in a period, he gets 15% from 0 to 100 000 (15000), 20% from the threshold 100000 to 200000 (20000*20%=4000), total 19 000

The mysql query detailed in the mysqlfiddle details the working formula:

sum((s.NGR - r.tier_min) * r.dif_rate) as SlideCom

And the final query looks like:

```
+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Agent  | APmonth | FirstMonth |  NGR  | FIXEDCOM | VARCOM2  |
+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| AGENT1 |       3 |          0 | 16802 |        0 | 2520.327 |
| AGENT2 |      17 |          2 |  7926 |       60 | 1188.975 |
| AGENT3 |       3 |          0 |  6541 |        0 |   981.15 |
| AGENT4 |       4 |          0 |  5513 |        0 |   826.95 |
| AGENT5 |       1 |          0 |     3 |        0 |      0.6 |
| AGENT6 |       1 |          0 |     1 |        0 |     0.21 |
+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

My issues:

- I cannot fix the issue where i need EACH agent to have its specific sliding scale of commission, and relate the AGENT field in the Commissions table to its corresponding Agent's Sales (NGR). I tried to modified the query adding to

JOIN commissions r ON r.tier_min <= s.NGR  AND s.Agent= a.Agent

but it does not work.
Any help on this issue would be a great help since I have been trying to do this for a while on my own with my limited Mysql skills;)

Thanks!

full data in case on sql fiddle issue:

```
  CREATE TABLE commissions
(`id` int, `tier_min` double, `tier_max` double, `com_rate` double, `dif_rate` double, `agent` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO commissions
(`id`, `tier_min`, `tier_max`, `com_rate`, `dif_rate`, `agent`)
VALUES
(1, 0, 100000, .15, .15, 'AGENT4'),
(3, 100000.001, 200000, .2, .05, 'AGENT4'),
(4, 200000.001, 300000, .25, .05, 'AGENT4'),
(5, 300000.001, 500000, .3, .05, 'AGENT4'),
(6, 500000.001, 10000000, .35, .05, 'AGENT4')
;


CREATE TABLE Online_customer_activity_v2
(`id` int, `Date` datetime, `Customers` varchar(100), `Agent` varchar(100), `Real_Money` int, `_Bonuses` int, `Total_Bets` int,  `Total_Win_Loss` int)
;

INSERT INTO Online_customer_activity_v2
(`id`, `Date`, `Customers`, `Agent`, `Real_Money`, `_Bonuses`, `Total_Bets`, `Total_Win_Loss`)
Values
(6813, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'KingOfPop', 'AGENT2',101000,1000,4000,100500),
(6814, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'Serena77', 'AGENT4',130000,1000,514500,120000),
(6815, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'KerymNY', 'AGENT3',376,0,1267.65,375.93),
(6816, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'whatthelol', 'AGENT1',130,0,6233.5,119.4993),
(6817, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'Noukashi', 'AGENT2',0,0,343.4,49.8),
(6818, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'SeaSunBeach', 'AGENT2',30,0,654.5,30),
(6819, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'Rizo_090', 'AGENT3',400,0,2675,-1165),
(6820, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 'Rizo_090', 'AGENT3',7900,1200,140168,30199)
;

CREATE TABLE Online_playerdatabase_v2
(`id` int,  `Player` varchar(50), `Agent` varchar(50),  `Sign_Up_Date` varchar(12),  `First_Deposit_Date` varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO Online_playerdatabase_v2
(`id`, `Player`, `Agent`, `Sign_Up_Date`, `First_Deposit_Date`)
VALUES
(75, 'KerymNY', 'AGENT3', '2015-02-21', '2015-02-26'),
(137, 'Rizo_090', 'AGENT3', '2015-10-23', '2015-10-23'),
(286, 'KingOfPop', 'AGENT2', '2016-10-03', '2016-12-21'),
(6, 'Noukashi', 'AGENT2', '2016-07-21', '2016-07-22'),
(294, 'Serena77', 'AGENT4', '2016-10-09', '2017-01-02'),
(160, 'whatthelol', 'AGENT1', '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),
(360, 'SeaSunBeach', 'AGENT2', '2016-04-18', '2016-04-18')
;
SELECT
    a.Agent ,
    t2.APmonth ,
    COALESCE(t8.FirstMonth , 0) AS FirstMonth ,

    TRUNCATE(a.NGR , 0) AS NGR ,


    COALESCE(t8.FirstMonth , 0) * 30 AS FIXEDCOM ,

    COALESCE(yy.SlideCom , 0) AS VARCOM2 ,
    TRUNCATE(
        COALESCE(t8.FirstMonth , 0) * 30 + COALESCE(yy.SlideCom , 0) ,
        0
    ) AS totalCOM
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Online_customer_activity_v2.Agent ,
            sum(
                Online_customer_activity_v2._Bonuses
            ) AS BONUS ,
            sum(
                Online_customer_activity_v2.Total_Win_Loss
            ) - sum(
                Online_customer_activity_v2._Bonuses
            ) AS NGR 
        FROM
            Online_customer_activity_v2
        WHERE
            (
                Online_customer_activity_v2.Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01'
                AND '2017-01-12'
                AND Agent <> 'NOAGENT'
            )
        GROUP BY
            Online_customer_activity_v2.Agent
    ) a
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        Agent ,
        count(First_Deposit_Date) AS FirstMonth
    FROM
        Online_playerdatabase_v2
    WHERE
        Online_playerdatabase_v2.First_Deposit_Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01'
    AND '2017-01-12'
    GROUP BY
        Agent
) t8 ON a.Agent = t8.Agent
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        Online_customer_activity_v2.Agent ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(Customers)) AS APmonth
    FROM
        Online_customer_activity_v2
    WHERE
        (
            Online_customer_activity_v2.Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01'
            AND '2017-01-12'
            AND Agent <> 'NOAGENT'
        )
    AND Online_customer_activity_v2.Total_Bets > 0
    GROUP BY
        Agent
) AS t2 ON a.Agent = t2.Agent

LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        s.Agent ,
        sum((s.NGR - r.tier_min) * r.dif_rate) SlideCom
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                Date ,
                Online_customer_activity_v2.Agent ,
                sum(
                    Online_customer_activity_v2.Total_Win_Loss
                ) - sum(
                    Online_customer_activity_v2._Bonuses
                ) AS NGR
            FROM
                Online_customer_activity_v2
            WHERE


                    Agent <> 'NOAGENT'

            AND (Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01'
            AND '2017-01-12')

            GROUP BY
                Agent ,
                date_format(Date , '%Y-%m')
        ) s
    JOIN commissions r ON r.tier_min <= s.NGR
    GROUP BY
        Agent
) yy ON a.Agent = yy.Agent
ORDER BY
    NGR DESC;
```

Comment: Are the number of commission rates fixed or per agent?

Comment: Hello, the commission are per agent, so each agent can have a different scale (ex: AGENT1: 10% from 0 to 100 000, AGENT2: 15% from 0 to 100 000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is you are looking for:

```
SeLeCt t5.Agent,t6.APmonth,t6.FirstMonth,t5.NGR,t5.toRate,t5.comm  FrOm
(
    SELECT t2.Agent,t2.NGR,ROUND(sum(t2.toRate),2) AS 'toRate',ROUND(sum(t2.comm),2) AS 'comm' FROM
    (
        select t1.Agent,t1.NGR,if(t1.NGR-c.tier_min>0,
                                        if(t1.NGR>c.tier_max,c.tier_max-c.tier_min,t1.NGR-c.tier_min),
                                                            0) as 'toRate', 
                if(t1.NGR-c.tier_min>0,
                                        if(t1.NGR>c.tier_max,c.tier_max-c.tier_min,t1.NGR-c.tier_min),
                                                            0)*c.com_rate as 'comm'
        from myDB.commissions c ,
        (
        SELECT ocav2.Agent, sum(ocav2.Total_Win_Loss - ocav2._Bonuses) as 'NGR'
        FROM myDB.Online_customer_activity_v2 ocav2
        GROUP BY ocav2.Agent
        ) t1
        where c.agent = t1.Agent
    ) t2
    GROUP BY t2.Agent

) t5 LeFt JoIn

(
    select t3.Agent,t3.APmonth,if(t4.FirstMonth is null,0,t4.FirstMonth) as 'FirstMonth' from
    (
        SELECT oca.Agent,COUNT(DISTINCT(oca.Customers)) AS 'APmonth'
        FROM Online_customer_activity_v2 oca
        WHERE oca.Total_Bets>0 AND oca.Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-12'
        GROUP BY oca.Agent

    ) t3 LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
        opv2.Agent ,
        count(opv2.First_Deposit_Date) AS 'FirstMonth'
    FROM
        Online_playerdatabase_v2 opv2
    WHERE
        opv2.First_Deposit_Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-12'
    GROUP BY
        opv2.Agent
    ) t4
    on t3.Agent=t4.Agent
) t6 On t5.Agent=t6.Agent
;
```

Remember change "`myDB`" by your database

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t( id int,  tier_min  int, tier_max int, com_rate decimal(10,2), dif_rate decimal(10,2), agent varchar(10));
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(  1 ,          0 ,   100000,     0.15 ,     0.15 , 'AGENT4'),
(  3 , 100000.001 ,   200000 ,      0.2 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT4'),
(  4 , 200000.001 ,   300000 ,     0.25 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT4'),
(  5 , 300000.001 ,   500000 ,      0.3 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT4'),
(  6 , 500000.001 , 10000000 ,     0.35 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT4'),
(  7 ,          0 ,   10000 ,     0.15 ,     0.15 , 'AGENT1'),
(  8 , 10000.001 , 15000 ,      0.2 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT1'),
(  9 , 15000.001 , 20000 ,      0.3 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT1'),

(  10 ,          0 ,   100000,     0.15 ,     0.15 , 'AGENT6'),
(  11 , 100000.001 ,   200000 ,      0.2 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT6'),
(  12 , 200000.001 ,   300000 ,     0.25 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT6'),
(  13 , 300000.001 ,   500000 ,      0.3 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT6'),
(  14 , 500000.001 , 10000000 ,     0.35 ,     0.05 , 'AGENT6')
;


drop table if exists agent;
create table agents ( Agent varchar(10) , APmonth int, FirstMonth int,  NGR  int, FIXEDCOM int, VARCOM2  decimal(10,2));
truncate table agents;
insert into agents values
( 'AGENT1' ,       3 ,          0 , 16802 ,        0 , 2520.327), 
( 'AGENT2' ,      17 ,          2 ,  7926 ,       60 , 1188.975), 
( 'AGENT3' ,       3 ,          0 ,  6541 ,        0 ,   981.15), 
( 'AGENT4' ,       4 ,          0 ,  5513 ,        0 ,   826.95), 
( 'AGENT5' ,       1 ,          0 ,     3 ,        0 ,      0.6), 
( 'AGENT6' ,       1 ,          0 , 750000,        0 ,     0.21);
```

Try this

```
select u.sagent, u.ngr,
        u.amt1+u.amt2+u.amt3+u.amt4+u.amt5 as Commamt,
        u.com1+u.com2+u.com3+u.com4+u.com5 as Comm
from 
(
SELECT T.SAGENT,T.NGR,t.comrate1,
            if(t.ngr <= t.maxtier1 , t.ngr ,t.maxtier1) amt1,
            ifnull(t.comrate1 * if(t.ngr <= t.maxtier1 , t.ngr ,t.maxtier1),0) com1,
            t.comrate2,
            if(t.ngr >= t.mintier2 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier2, t.ngr - t.maxtier1,if(t.ngr > t.mintier3,t.maxtier2 - t.maxtier1,0)) amt2,
            ifnull(t.comrate2 * if(t.ngr >= t.mintier2 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier2, t.ngr - t.maxtier1,if(t.ngr > t.mintier3,t.maxtier2 - t.maxtier1,0)),0) com2,
            t.comrate3,
           if(t.ngr >= t.mintier3 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier3, t.ngr - t.maxtier2,if(t.ngr > t.mintier4,t.maxtier3 - t.maxtier2,0)) amt3,
           ifnull(t.comrate3 * if(t.ngr >= t.mintier3 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier3, t.ngr - t.maxtier2,if(t.ngr > t.mintier4,t.maxtier3 - t.maxtier2,0)),0) com3,
            t.comrate4, 
            if(t.ngr >= t.mintier4 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier4, t.ngr - t.maxtier3,if(t.ngr > t.mintier5,t.maxtier4 - t.maxtier3,0)) amt4,
            ifnull(t.comrate4 * if(t.ngr >= t.mintier4 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier4, t.ngr - t.maxtier3,if(t.ngr > t.mintier5,t.maxtier4 - t.maxtier3,0)),0) com4,
            t.comrate5,
            if(t.ngr >= t.mintier5 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier5, t.ngr - t.maxtier4,if(t.ngr > 9999999999,t.maxtier5 - t.maxtier4,0)) amt5,
            ifnull(t.comrate5 * if(t.ngr >= t.mintier5 and t.ngr <= t.maxtier5, t.ngr - t.maxtier4,if(t.ngr > 9999999999,t.maxtier5 - t.maxtier4,0)),0) com5
FROM
(
select s.agent SAGENT,a.*,
         max(case when s.rn = 1 then s.tier_min end) mintier1,
         max(case when s.rn = 1 then s.tier_max end) maxtier1,
         max(case when s.rn = 1 then s.com_rate end) comrate1,
         max(case when s.rn = 2 then s.tier_min end) mintier2,
         max(case when s.rn = 2 then s.tier_max end) maxtier2,
         max(case when s.rn = 2 then s.com_rate end) comrate2,
         max(case when s.rn = 3 then s.tier_min end) mintier3,
         max(case when s.rn = 3 then s.tier_max end) maxtier3,
         max(case when s.rn = 3 then s.com_rate end) comrate3,
         max(case when s.rn = 4 then s.tier_min end) mintier4,
         max(case when s.rn = 4 then s.tier_max end) maxtier4,
         max(case when s.rn = 4 then s.com_rate end) comrate4,
         max(case when s.rn = 5 then s.tier_min end) mintier5,
         max(case when s.rn = 5 then s.tier_max end) maxtier5,
         max(case when s.rn = 5 then s.com_rate end) comrate5
from 
(
select t.*,
        if (t.agent <> @p ,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=t.agent 
from (select @rn:=0,@p:='') rn,t 
order by t.agent, t.id
) s 
join agents a on a.agent = s.agent
group by s.agent
) T
) u
```

Note I am assuming a max number of rates as 5
The sub query s allocates a row number to each rate per agent (1-5) which is then joined and pivoted to create 1 row per agent.The sub query t then works out the amount that falls into each commission band and the value of the commission. The outer query then simply totals the amounts that fall into each band as a cross check and the final commission amount.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this solution. I am trying to achieve this without a strict max number of threshold.

Comment: If you don't have a max limit then you will have to go dynamic sql - but are there really going to be more than 10 say?